# Probleme with custom user Django

Tags: python, django

I have to create a custom user at my Django project :

```
class CustomUser(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, unique=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    telephone_nb = models.IntegerField()
```

I created also a specific table at my DB named customUser. But when I try to save a CustomUser object, I have this error message :

> OperationalError at /test (1054, "Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list'")

Comment: I'm using 1.8 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to let django create the correct sql table for you based on your model

You can do this with [`manage.py syncdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb)

[syncdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) only creates new tables so you will have to delete the one you created

Comment: I'm working on Eclipse, I already tried syncdb command at eclipse but I still have the same problem. I created manually the CustomUser table at my database. You think that i have to delete this table and let django create the table?
Thanks